# windows Batch file programming - get COMPORT number

Tags: batch-file

I want to get certain comport number in my batch script (bat),
  then I can do further operation to this comport.

For example, I want to get the number of following usb diag port:
  Qualcomm HS-USB Diagnostics 9091 (COM168)

How to get the port number (168) in batch file?
  Thanks.

Comment: ...How do you usually get it?

Comment: I have to get input from the user to know which port to access, which is not enough automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: wmic /format:list strips trailing spaces (at least for path win32_pnpentity)
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:list ^| find "COM"') do (
    call :setCOM "%%~J"
)

:: display all _COM* variables
set _COM

:: end main batch
goto :EOF

:setCOM <WMIC_output_line>
:: sets _COM#=line
setlocal
set "str=%~1"
set "num=%str:*(COM=%"
set "num=%num:)=%"
echo %num%
set str=%str:(COM=&rem.%
echo %str%

if %str% == "Qualcomm HS-USB Diagnostics 9091"
echo port number is %num%

endlocal & set "_COM%num%=%str%"

goto :EOF
```